# Where can I find unbiased news coverage of the US election run-up?

Tags: united-states, election

I realise that requests for lists of resources are generally off-topic on SE, but so are subjective questions (and what in politics isn't), so I hope there's leeway here.

I'm European, and so have little first-hand knowledge of what's really going on in US politics, and largely rely on media coverage. Is it fair and balanced? Who knows.

Searching on the internet, I can easily find convincing arguments drawing parallels between Trump and Hitler, and others that make Trump sound mostly reasonable.

Unfortunately, examples like http://www.forbes.com/sites/stuartanderson/2015/08/17/trump-the-hypocrite-investing-overseas-fine-for-him/#11b13a2c936b mix good factual questions (overseas outsourcing clothing manufacture for the US markt) with blatant bias (overseas hotels are not an alternative to US hotels).

What unbiased internet resources are out there?

Comment: Nowhere. Everyone has biases. The only solution is to read sources biased different ways and synthesize an unbiased view from that.

Comment: Having said that, rule of thumb is, if someone has no better argument than comparing someone to Hitler, they probably simply don't have rational arguments and not worth listening to

Comment: @user4012 Replace jews with muslims, and look at the stance on generations of immigrants losing citizenship - you can see how it looks from the outside without context

Comment: you might want to learn to distinguish true claims from slander... http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/30892/1044. As I said above, if someone has no better argument than comparing someone to Hitler... they simply have no arguments at all.

Comment: @user4012 Thanks for that link; it's good to see the extra details

Comment: I'm pretty sure 'unbiased' news coverage doesn't exist. Every publication has some bias.

Comment: "and largely rely on media coverage. Is it fair and balanced?" It is not.  Polling of reporters and news editors show that an overwhelming majority are liberal in their views and vote for Democrats. Whether or not they truly try to hide their bias, and I'm sure a lot of them do, it comes through regularly. http://www.mrc.org/media-reality-check/bias-minute-tallying-network-news-agenda-2015 is an interesting article. It's not unbiased, but I would encourage you to skip toward the bottom and see how much you've heard about the stories that have been skipped and whether you think them newsworthy.

Comment: Because reporters tend to lean left, most news sources have a leftward bias.  In America that has led to the creation of news stations that cater to voters who don't share that bias - and because they are explicitly doing so they tend to be much more biased even while being fewer in number.

Comment: Everyone may have biases, themselves, but part of following professional objective journalistic standards is following practices that will minimize them.  The idea that you can't get factually objective reporting is a myth perpetuated by those who don't like what objective facts say about their viewpoints, generally. It's usually those who complain that top tier news sources aren't factual, objective or professional that gravitate, ironically, towards sources that don't follow those standards.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, it's impossible for a news source to have *no* bias.  Even if everything is reported perfectly neutrally, there's still the editorial decisions of what stories to report on.  No site can possibly report on *everything* that happens.  Additionally, a large part of good journalism is putting facts into context, since the average reader probably doesn't know offhand whether (for example) 50 billion dollars is a large portion of the federal budget or not.  (It's around 1%)  But the choice of which context to put those facts into also introduces bias.

---

That said, I generally follow the election on [FiveThirtyEight](http://fivethirtyeight.com/politics/).  It approaches the election from the perspective of statistics:  What do the demographics look like? What does polling show?  What historical precedents are there?  It touches on most of the major news stories, because of how they affect polling, but doesn't get into much detail.  In so doing, it does manage to be *relatively* bias-free.  It's by no means comprehensive coverage, but it's a good bird's-eye view of where the election is and where it's likely to go.
<sub>(Although, they completely misjudged Trump's chances early on and didn't expect him to do nearly as well as he is doing... but their reasoning at the time was based on historical precedent, and there's never been a candidate like Trump.)</sub>

Comment: Nate Silver is extremely liberal, but most of the time he very successfully manages to disassociate his own views from his analysis. He slips once in a while, but VERY infrequently. Unfortunately, some of the new 538 writers aren't nearly as successful.

Comment: Ironically(?) polling and analysis of polling, itself, generates bias. :)

Comment: @blip - I wouldn't say that *polling* generates bias, although you can certainly have a biased poll.  But all reporting on it falls into all the possible sources of bias as any other reporting, plus the ones inherent in interpreting a poll.  It's way to easy to take away a flat statement of "this is the case" from what's really a "this has 60% chance of being true, and 90% chance of being close to true"

Comment: @Bobson I was referring to the broader issue that polls influence voters. The simple acting of doing polling and producing analysis ultimately further biases things.

Comment: @blip There's also a good episode of Yes Minister (or PM) that illustrates how you can get the answer you want by asking the right questions first. [Leading Questions](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiDrOaQs-vLAhXH7RQKHT_dAlkQyCkIHzAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DG0ZZJXw4MTA&usg=AFQjCNER07Z4meuI0tT59Fq37Qwa8_PJXA&sig2=n9Vm7BCFs3ecQt-bxlQSvQ)

Comment: @PhilLello yes, excellent point, too. Most polls are naturally biased as well.

Comment: The problem with a site that just covers the statistics and demographics is that it skips important information like what the candidates actually say and stand for.

Comment: @Readin - I agree, to some extent. That's why I made sure to point out that it *isn't* comprehensive. On the other hand, there's enough discussion of why certain candidates appeal to certain audiences that you can get a high-level feel for each candidate.  I wouldn't recommend making any voting decisions based solely on 538's reporting, but it's a good jumping off point for further reading. That said, I *am* in the US, so coverage is much more pervasive than it would be in the OP's country. My impressions of how much you can learn may be colored by other sources of coverage.